# Removing and adding back transition & width style on div does not remove style

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to create a progress bar for an image carousel on hover. When the carousel reaches its end the progress bar also should reset but it doesn't.

What I do is remove the style of width and transition when the carousel ends and add it back.

Here is the code. I am doing it in vuejs.

```
if (!nextSlide) {
          this.carouselProgress.style.transition = "none";
          this.carouselProgress.style.width = 0 + "%";
          currentSlide.classList.remove("current-slide");
          this.initialSlide.classList.add("current-slide");
          nextSlide = this.initialSlide;
          this.carouselProgress.style.width = 100 + "%";
          this.carouselProgress.style.transition = `width ${
              1.5 * numberOfSlide
          }s ease-in`;
        }
```

You can see in the first 2 lines and last 2 lines in the if statement how I am removing and reapplying the styles but it does not work.

Can anyone suggest me an alternate solution.

Comment: you can create two different classes, one for adding and one for removing. Then apply conditional class to the element using the nextSlide parameter

Comment: I could do that but my transition can change and I wont be able to calculate transition time in class.

Comment: can you try placing watcher on nextSlide and do the logic in there on the basis of it's value?

Comment: Nope same effect. Tried the watcher.

Comment: okay. Please try using computed properties and then pass them as props via :style